# Output the size of multiple PDF files and their corresponding text files in csv or xlsx format

Tags: python

I have around 500 PDFs on my computer, that I have been able to convert to text files, which are stored in a separate folder. 
I employed the following to get the size of the PDF files:

```
import PyPDF2
import glob
from os import path
import os
from pathlib import *

statis =[]
base_path = Path("//File Path//PDFs")
pdf_files = list(base_path.glob('*.pdf'))
for f in pdf_files:
    statinfo = os.stat(f)
    size = statinfo.st_size
    statis.append(os.stat(f).st_size)  # this prints the size adding one by one, solve
    print(statis)
```

I have the corresponding text files, for which I have done the same thing as above.

What I need as output is the name of the PDF file, the size of the file, and the size of the corresponding text file in csv format
I have tried printing the output to csv, but need the file size from the text file as well

Comment: `open()`, `read()`, `close()`

Comment: if text file has the same name then get pdf name, remove extension (even usinng text slicing) and add .txt extension to get text file.

Comment: I have the text files, I want to print the sizes of all the text and pdf  files in the same csv folder

Comment: `glob` gives you all PDF filenames. For every PDF file, get its name and replace extension to get filename of text file. You will have pairs PDF and txt filenames. Now you can get sizes for both and write in csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `glob('*.txt')` on folder with text files and then use `zip()` to create pairs `(pdf, txt)` and then you can get they sizes, put all as list/tuple in `statis` and later all write in `csv`. To make sure I sort names.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import csv

statis = []

pdf_folder = Path("folder_with_pdfs")
txt_folder = Path("folder_with_txts")

pdf_files = sorted(pdf_folder.glob('*.pdf'))
txt_files = sorted(txt_folder.glob('*.txt'))

for (pdf, txt) in zip(pdf_files, txt_files):
    pdf_size = os.stat(pdf).st_size
    txt_size = os.stat(txt).st_size

    statis.append([pdf.name, txt.name, pdf_size, txt_size, pdf_size-txt_size])

    print(pdf.name, pdf_size)
    print(txt.name, txt_size)
    print('---')

with open('output.csv', 'w') as fp:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(fp)
    csv_writer.writerow(['pdf name', 'txt name', 'pdf size', 'txt size', 'size diff'])
    csv_writer.writerows(statis)
```

But it will have problem if there are missing files. It will create pairs with no corresponding names. It is better to get name of pdf file and generate path for text file.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import csv

statis = []

pdf_folder = Path("folder_with_pdfs")
txt_folder = Path("folder_with_txts")

pdf_files = pdf_folder.glob('*.pdf')

for pdf in pdf_files:
    txt = txt_folder / pdf.name.replace('.pdf', '.txt')

    if not txt.exists():
        print('[!] missing:', txt.name)
        continue

    pdf_size = os.stat(pdf).st_size
    txt_size = os.stat(txt).st_size

    statis.append([pdf.name,txt.name,pdf_size, txt_size, pdf_size-txt_size]])

    print(pdf.name, pdf_size)
    print(txt.name, txt_size)
    print('---')

with open('output.csv', 'w') as fp:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(fp)
    csv_writer.writerow(['pdf name', 'txt name', 'pdf size', 'txt size', 'size diff'])
    csv_writer.writerows(statis)
```

Comment: this works. to remove the empty line per observation in the csv file, I used `open('output.csv', 'w', newline = '') as fp: `